# Assigning an id to this.state to play the correct animation? React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated, lottie

I have been working ways to figure this problem out. The way I have my code set up is that I have animations in a flatlist and it has created a single animation for how ever many data I have. For example, my JSON data contains 8 categories, my flatlist automatically contains 8 animations. Here is my code:

```
<FlatList

   data={ this.state.dataSource}

   ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}


   renderItem={({item}) => <View>


   <Card>




     <View>
     <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={this.anim_star.bind(this, item.id)}
      style={{position:'absolute',  height: '100%', width: '100%',}}>
      <Animation
      progress={this.state.progress[item.id]}
      source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}
      style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', position: 'absolute'}}
      resizeMode={`contain`}

      />
      </TouchableOpacity>



     </View>

   </Card>


   </View>


 }

 keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
 removeClippedSubviews
```

/>

Right here, I have been trying to give those animations a unique id (item.id). Here is the function I used for binding:

```
    anim_star = (id) => {

  let progress = this.state.progress;
  progress[id] = new Animated.Value(0);

    this.setState({ progress });
console.log(this.state.progress);
  Animated.timing(this.state.progress, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 2000,
    easing: Easing.linear,
  }).start();

}
```

I did a `console.log` to see my results and I can see the correct id being displayed, but I don't think it's corresponding correctly. The animation does not play at all. When I take off the `[item.id]` in the `progress=this.state.progress`, the animation works, but every animation in that flatlist plays. I want to play that one animation with the correct id.

Here is my console results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP41z.jpg

And lastly here are what the constructors look like:

```
    constructor(props)
{
  super(props);

  this.state = {
  isLoading: true,
  id: '',
  dataSource: '',
  progress: {}, 
};
```

Also to note, when all animations did play I console logged those results and noticed that the `_children` array have `[AnimatedProps]` and I think that is what triggers the animation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zigB6.jpg

The `array(8)` represents all the data that have animations triggered. The reason why the 10 is still there is because I didn't remove:

```
let progress = this.state.progress;
  progress[id] = new Animated.Value(0);
```

I tried searching for some answers similar to my problem, but I could not find a single solution. Is there a way to play animations uniquely?

Also you may notice that  is not part of the react-native library, that is because I am using Lottie to play json animations.